# Add column automatically when the base table changes in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I am using Postgres.

`table1` columns: `id`, `name`

`table2_hist` columns: `id`, `name`

If I add one more column `salary` in `table1` (only the column, no data), is this possible to also add that column to `table2`?

Like this, I have multiple tables to add columns to. Is there any script for this?

Comment: This looks like a badly normalized data model. table1 and table2 should actually be only one table, possibly with a column identifying the "type" it belongs to. Table inheritance _might_ be one solution to this though, or - if you were using an up-to-date Postgres version - you could use [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) for this.

Comment: Postgres 9.1 and 9.3 and [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE). You should plan an upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible.

Comment: I need like this only

Comment: Why did you add the MySQL tag? Which database are you **really** using?

Comment: i want in both servers mysql and postgres.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, one way would be to use an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) that is triggered by an `ALTER TABLE`. In an event trigger written in C you could analyze the parse tree and take appropriate measures.

But this seems like a cumbersome way to go.

Another idea in PostgreSQL would be to use inheritance. Since the tables have the same columns, one could inherit from the other:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id integer PRIMARY KEY, name text);

CREATE TABLE table2 () INHERITS (table1);

\d table2
              Table "laurenz.table2"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           | not null | 
 name   | text    |           |          | 
Inherits: table1

ALTER TABLE table1 ADD newcol bytea;

\d table2
              Table "laurenz.table2"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           | not null | 
 name   | text    |           |          | 
 newcol | bytea   |           |          | 
Inherits: table1
```

But I don't think you can find a solution that will work for both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

I think it is a mistake to try and do that automatically in the database. You should find some other way to make sure that no table is modified without a corresponding modification of the history table.